# WCF Service returns page content of .svc (The content type text/html exception)

Tags: c#, wcf

I developed a WCF server locally and tested it and it works fine (returns string "Hello World"). It's hosted in IIS

But when I deploy it to my website hosted on GoDaddy, server sends the page content of Service1.svc (description content) instead of "Hello World!", which the client doesn't expect nor handle.

client config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMessage2" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://mywebaddress/myservice/Service1.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMessage2"
            contract="ServiceReference2.IMessage" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMessage2" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Server Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
<httpModules>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
</httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="HelloServiceBehavior" name="HelloService.HelloService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
      contract="HelloService.IMessage" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HelloServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
  <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"
    preCondition="managedHandler"/>
</modules>
<!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

client crashes when calling service method:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message doesn't match the content type of the binding
```

Service response on Fiddler which is the exact content of www.XXXXX.com/Service.svc in browser:

```
 <HTML><HEAD><link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" href="http://XXXXXXX.net/myservice/Service1.svc?disco"/><STYLE type="text/css">#content{ FONT-SIZE: 0.7em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 2em; MARGIN-LEFT: 30px}BODY{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-LEFT: 0px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white}P{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 12px; COLOR: #000000; FONT-FAMILY: Verdana}PRE{BORDER-RIGHT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-RIGHT: 5px; BORDER-TOP: #f0f0e0 1px solid; MARGIN-TOP: -5px; PADDING-LEFT: 5px; FONT-SIZE: 1.2em; PADDING-BOTTOM: 5px; BORDER-LEFT: #f0f0e0 1px solid; PADDING-TOP: 5px; BORDER-BOTTOM: #f0f0e0 1px solid; FONT-FAMILY: Courier New; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #e5e5cc}.heading1{MARGIN-TOP: 0px; PADDING-LEFT: 15px; FONT-WEIGHT: normal; FONT-SIZE: 26px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px; PADDING-BOTTOM: 3px; MARGIN-LEFT: -30px; WIDTH: 100%; COLOR: #ffffff; PADDING-TOP: 10px; FONT-FAMILY: Tahoma; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #003366}.intro{MARGIN-LEFT: -15px}</STYLE><TITLE>HelloService Service</TITLE></HEAD><BODY><DIV id="content"><P class="heading1">HelloService Service</P><BR/><P class="intro">You have created a service.<P class='intro'>To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:</P> <BR/><PRE>svcutil.exe <A HREF="http://alqasm.net/myservice/Service1.svc?wsdl">http://alqasm.net/myservice/Service1.svc?wsdl</A></PRE><P>You can also access the service description as a single file:<BR/><PRE><A HREF="http://alqasm.net/myservice/Service1.svc?singleWsdl">http://alqasm.net/myservice/Service1.svc?singleWsdl</A></PRE></P></P><P class="intro"/>This will generate a configuration file and a code file that contains the client class. Add the two files to your client application and use the generated client class to call the Service. For example:<BR/><P class='intro'><B>C#</B></P><PRE><font color="blue">class </font><font color="teal">Test
</font>{
<font color="blue">    static void </font>Main()
    {
        <font color="teal">MessageClient</font> client = <font color="blue">new </font><font color="teal">MessageClient</font>();

<font color="green">        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

</font><font color="green">        // Always close the client.
</font>        client.Close();
    }
}
</PRE><BR/><P class='intro'><B>Visual Basic</B></P><PRE><font color="blue">Class </font><font color="teal">Test
</font><font color="blue">    Shared Sub </font>Main()
<font color="blue">        Dim </font>client As <font color="teal">MessageClient</font> = <font color="blue">New </font><font color="teal">MessageClient</font>()
<font color="green">        ' Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.

</font><font color="green">        ' Always close the client.
</font>        client.Close()
<font color="blue">    End Sub
</font><font color="blue">End Class</font></PRE></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

Your support is much appreciated

Comment: What is the version of IIS in Godaddy.

Comment: @ApurvaSaxena IIS 7.0

Comment: @ApurvaSaxena please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add MIME type for .SVC in IIS or for easy fix use can register asp.net in IIS. See link msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/k6h9cz8h(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: As far as I know, registering asp.net in IIS will solve the issue, if it was local. My local version of WCF is running and responding OK. However, the issue is on my remote webservice.

Comment: Please check with GoDaddy, may be they haven't done that, let me know if that is not the case...

Comment: I ended up changing my web hosting to another who's recommended by ASP.NET and my web service worked on the new hosting environment. It seems GoDaddy isn't a good choice when it comes to WCF. Many thanks for the effort